# Scala & for comprehensions: Compile errors when implementing map, flatmap, and filter as instance methods that rely on a companion object

Tags: scala, traits, type-mismatch, for-comprehension

My apologies in advance for any questionable synax. I'm learning a new language, and definitely appreciate the help!

For the purposes of learning, I'm trying to setup a custom list implementation (named Mlist, for 'my list') that can work with Scala's for comprehensions. In trying to do this, I'm running into a compile error that has me stumped.

Here's the code in question:

```
sealed trait Mlist[+A] {
  def map[A,B](f: A => B): Mlist[B]
  def flatMap[A,B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B]
  def filter[A](f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A]
}

case object Mnil extends Mlist[Nothing] {

  def map[A,B](f: A => B): Mlist[B] = {
    Mnil
  }

  def flatMap[A, B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = {
    Mnil
  }

  def filter[A](f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = {
    Mnil
  }

}

case class Mcons[+A](head: A, tail: Mlist[A]) extends Mlist[A] {

  def map[A,B](f: A => B): Mlist[B] = {
    Mlist.map(this)(f)
  }

  def flatMap[A,B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = {
    Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
  }

  def filter[A](f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = {
    Mlist.filter(this)(f)
  }

}

object Mlist {

  def map[A,B](l: Mlist[A])(f: A => B): Mlist[B] = {
    foldRight(l, Mnil: Mlist[B])((h, t) => Mcons(f(h), t))
  }

  def filter[A](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = {
    foldRight(as, Mnil: Mlist[A])((a, acc) => if (f(a)) Mcons(a, acc) else acc)
  }

  def flatMap[A, B](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = {
    concat(map(as)(f))
  }
}

object Mlist {

  def map[A,B](l: Mlist[A])(f: A => B): Mlist[B] = {
    foldRight(l, Mnil: Mlist[B])((h, t) => Mcons(f(h), t))
  }

  def filter[A](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = {
    foldRight(as, Mnil: Mlist[A])((a, acc) => if (f(a)) Mcons(a, acc) else acc)
  }

  def flatMap[A, B](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = {
    concat(map(as)(f))
  }

}
```

The basic idea is to have a trait that defines the methods implemented by my two Mlist classes. Rather than reimplement instance methods for things like map, I'm trying to call into my helper object to reuse its methods.

Here's the compile error I'm seeing:

```
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method map) => B
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => B
[error]     Mlist.map(this)(f)
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:35: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method flatMap) => Mlist[B]
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => Mlist[B]
[error]     Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method filter) => Boolean
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => Boolean
[error]     Mlist.filter(this)(f)
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Mlist[A(in class Mcons)]
[error]  required: Mlist[A(in method filter)]
[error]     Mlist.filter(this)(f)
```

And, in case it's at all useful, here's the (untested and perhaps completely dysfunctional) for comprehension I eventually intend to implement:

```
def combos(list: Mlist[A]): Mlist[Mlist[A]] = {
  for {
    el <- list
    combo <- combos(tail(list))
  } yield {
    setHead(el, combo)
  }
}
```

Can anyone walk me through what my compile errors mean and how to solve them?

Comment: To answer more briefly than @jamborta, the problem is in your trait, you have redefined *A* in the the method declarations. The type *A* that those methods reference is *not* the same type *A* that you declared in the definition of *MList*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing your type parameter `A` defined in the `Mlist` trait with an identically-named type parameter in your `Mlist.map`, `Mlist.flatMap`, and `Mlist.filter` methods:

```
sealed trait Mlist[+A] {
//                  ↑
// this is a type parameter named `A`
  def map[A,B](f: A => B): Mlist[B]
  //      ↑
  // this is a completely different, totally unrelated type parameter, 
  // confusingly also named `A`
  def flatMap[A,B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B]
  def filter[A](f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A]
}
```

Scala is telling you this in the error message, where it tells you in parentheses after the name of the parameter *which* of the identically named `A`s and `B`s it is talking about:

```
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method map) => B
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => B
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]     Mlist.map(this)(f)
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:35: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method flatMap) => Mlist[B]
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => Mlist[B]
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]     Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A(in method filter) => Boolean
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]  required: A(in class Mcons) => Boolean
//                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]     Mlist.filter(this)(f)
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/jb/Desktop/dev/personal/functional-programming-scala/src/main/scala/Ch3Lists.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Mlist[A(in class Mcons)]
//                        ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]  required: Mlist[A(in method filter)]
//                        ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[error]     Mlist.filter(this)(f)
```

Maybe, the error messages become clearer if you use fresh names everywhere and don't shadow anything:

```
sealed trait Mlist[+A] {
  def map[B, C](f: B => C): Mlist[C]
  def flatMap[D, E](f: D => Mlist[E]): Mlist[E]
  def filter[F](f: F => Boolean): Mlist[F]
}

case object Mnil extends Mlist[Nothing] {
  def map[G, H](f: G => H): Mlist[H] = this
  def flatMap[I, J](f: I => Mlist[J]): Mlist[J] = this
  def filter[K](f: K => Boolean): Mlist[K] = this
}

case class Mcons[+L](head: L, tail: Mlist[L]) extends Mlist[L] {
  def map[M, N](f: M => N): Mlist[N] = Mlist.map(this)(f)
  def flatMap[O, P](f: O => Mlist[P]): Mlist[P] = Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
  def filter[Q](f: Q => Boolean): Mlist[Q] = Mlist.filter(this)(f)
}

object Mlist {
  def map[R, S](l: Mlist[R])(f: R => S): Mlist[S] = 
    foldRight(l, Mnil: Mlist[S])((h, t) => Mcons(f(h), t))

  def filter[T](as: Mlist[T])(f: T => Boolean): Mlist[T] = 
    foldRight(as, Mnil: Mlist[T])((a, acc) => if (f(a)) Mcons(a, acc) else acc)

  def flatMap[U, V](as: Mlist[U])(f: U => Mlist[V]): Mlist[V] =
    concat(map(as)(f))
}
```

This gives the following error message:

```
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : M => N
 required: L => N
             def map[M, N](f: M => N): Mlist[N] = Mlist.map(this)(f)
                                                                  ^
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : O => Mlist[P]
 required: L => Mlist[P]
             def flatMap[O, P](f: O => Mlist[P]): Mlist[P] = Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
                                                                                 ^
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Q => Boolean
 required: L => Boolean
             def filter[Q](f: Q => Boolean): Mlist[Q] = Mlist.filter(this)(f)
                                                                           ^
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Mlist[L]
 required: Mlist[Q]
             def filter[Q](f: Q => Boolean): Mlist[Q] = Mlist.filter(this)(f)
                                                                    ^
```

I hope it is now clear to see where your errors come from.

Note that you actually never use the type parameter of the trait or class anywhere, you *always* only use the type parameters of the methods. That surely sounds fishy; you need to actually use those type parameters!

```
sealed trait Mlist[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Mlist[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B]
  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A]
}

case object Mnil extends Mlist[Nothing] {
  def map[A, B](f: A => B): Mlist[B] = this
  def flatMap[A, B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = this
  def filter[A](f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = this
}

case class Mcons[+A](head: A, tail: Mlist[A]) extends Mlist[A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Mlist[B] = Mlist.map(this)(f)
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = Mlist.flatMap(this)(f)
  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = Mlist.filter(this)(f)
}

object Mlist {
  def map[A, B](l: Mlist[A])(f: A => B): Mlist[B] = 
    foldRight(l, Mnil: Mlist[B])((h, t) => Mcons(f(h), t))

  def filter[A](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = 
    foldRight(as, Mnil: Mlist[A])((a, acc) => if (f(a)) Mcons(a, acc) else acc)

  def flatMap[A, B](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] =
    concat(map(as)(f))
}
```

By the way, I think your abstractions are the wrong way around: surely, an external object such as the `Mlist` singleton object should *not* know about the internals of `Mcons` objects and manipulate them! An object should know how to manipulate itself, and nobody else should know about that. In fact, your abstractions are strangely mixed: `Mnil` *does* know how to deal with itself, but `Mcons` objects do not. This way looks much saner:

```
case class Mcons[+A](head: A, tail: Mlist[A]) extends Mlist[A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Mlist[B] = foldRight(Mnil: Mlist[B])((h, t) => Mcons(f(h), t))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = concat(map(f))
  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = 
    foldRight(Mnil: Mlist[A])((a, acc) => if (f(a)) Mcons(a, acc) else acc)
}

object Mlist {
  def map[A, B](l: Mlist[A])(f: A => B): Mlist[B] = l map f
  def filter[A](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Boolean): Mlist[A] = as filter f
  def flatMap[A, B](as: Mlist[A])(f: A => Mlist[B]): Mlist[B] = as flatMap f
}
```

Notice how both of the methods, the implementation method and the delegation mehod, in each pair got simpler? That's a good sign.